# Why the image is broken occasionally with the hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, hover

```
$(function () {
    $(".btn").on("mouseover",function(){
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("images", "images/hover"));
    });

    $(".btn").on("mouseleave",function(){
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("images/hover", "images"));
    });
});
```

The above code is the way I change the image when the user hover on the button, when user click on it , it will redirect to other page. And the Html element is like:

```
<a href="product.php"><img class="btn" src="images/index_03.gif" /></a>
```

The problem is , I am sure the path is correct , but when the user click on the button , during the time of loading the next page or in some case, when i hover on the image ,  the hovered image is not shown but broken link, why is it and how to fix it? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("images/hover", "images"));
```

This code will reload the image, every time (or from cache).

So, during the page loading as other data is also loading at the same time, onhover image loading will be slow or broken.

I suggest you should load both images at the same time and at the same position and show/hide them on hover to get faster results.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS sprites instead of javascript calls will eliminate mouseover flickering, and reduce the total number of http requests required for your site (making it load faster).

You can achieve the same 'mouseover' functionality by using the css ':hover' [pseudo element](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) to alter the 'clip' property of the image (supported in IE6 and above).

Check out these CSS Tricks articles: 
[CSS Sprites: What They Are, Why They’re Cool, and How To Use Them](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).
[CSS Sprites with Inline Images](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites-with-inline-images/)